# HTML Form Submit POST and checkbox treeview Value

Tags: php, jquery, html, treeview

I made an HTML page with a form containing some options and the values are sent via POST to a PHP page.

The HTML contains usual form inputs with checkboxes and text types, then I added checkboxes with treeview by jQuery, but when I click the *Submit* button, the values of the treeview checkboxes are not sent with the POST data. Why is that data not being sent along?

1. How can I get all checkbox values with form data (i.e. in the POST data)?
2. If the user selects the Parent checkboxes in treeview, how can I make it select all child checkboxes, and if a fraction of the child checkboxes are selected then parent checkbox will get square mark?
3. Can I make the form clear all selected checkboxes (including those in the treeview control) if the user clicks the *Reset* form button?

Can someone explain what is wrong or how to correct the following:

```
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="ConstructorMain.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>

            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Documents Generator</legend>


            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filename">File Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="filename" name="filename" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                    <span class="help-block">File name for the generated file</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Certified Or Non -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="type">Product Type</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="type-0">
                            <input type="radio" name="type" id="type-0" value="cert" checked="checked"> Certified Products
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="type-1">
                            <input type="radio" name="type" id="type-1" value="non"> Non-Certified Product
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="type-2">
                            <input type="radio" name="type" id="type-2" value="full"> Universal
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- AV & CC -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="avcc[]">Protection Type</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label for="avcc-0">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="avcc[]" id="avcc-0" value="AV"> Anti-virus
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label for="avcc-1">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="avcc[]" id="avcc-1" value="CC"> Complex Protection
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Product Line -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ostype">Operating System Platform</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div id="treeview-checkbox">
                        <ul>
                            <li>DSS
                                <ul>
                                    <li data-value="DSS-WIN-OS">Windows</li>
                                    <li data-value="DSS-LINUX-OS">Linux</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>SSS
                                <ul>
                                    <li data-value="SSS-WIN-OS">Windows</li>
                                    <li data-value="SSS-LINUX-OS">Linux</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>GSS
                                <ul>
                                    <li data-value="GSS-WIN-OS">Windows</li>
                                    <li data-value="GSS-LINUX-OS">Windows</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>




            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="products[]">Product</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label for="products-0">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" id="products-0" value="DSS">DSS

                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label for="products-1">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" id="products-1" value="SSS">SSS

                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label for="products-2">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" id="products-2" value="MSS"> MSS

                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label for="products-3">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" id="products-3" value="GSS"> GSS

                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label for="products-4">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" id="products-4" value="MoSS"> MoSS

                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Operating System -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ostype">Operating System Platform</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="ostype" name="ostype" class="form-control">
                        <option value="win">Windows Platform</option>
                        <option value="linx">Linux Platform</option>
                        <option value="allos">Both Platform</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Button (Double) -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="generate">Confirm Slection</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <button id="generate" name="generate" class="btn btn-primary">Generate File</button>
                    <button id="clearselection" name="clearselection" class="btn btn-inverse">Reset Selection</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-treeview/logger.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-treeview/treeview.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('#treeview-checkbox').treeview({
            debug: true,
            data: ['links', 'Do WHile loop']
        });
        $('#show-values').on('click', function() {
            $('#values').text(
                $('#treeview-checkbox').treeview('selectedValues')
            );
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few corrections and have answers to two out of the three of your questions:

1. I am not sure what the best way of handling this is but one method is to use javascript to set the name attribute on each checkbox. You can filter to only checkboxes where the value has a hyphen (i.e. *-*) to exclude the parent nodes (i.e.*DSS*, *SSS*, *GSS*). I used the click handler below:

   ```
   $('#generate').on('click', function() {
     var checkboxes = $('#treeview-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]');
     Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes,function(checkbox) {
       if (checkbox.value.indexOf('-') > -1 && checkbox.checked) { //only include checked child nodes
         checkbox.name = 'platform[]';
       }
     });
   });
   ```

   Also, it appears that the *data* property is used for pre-selecting checkboxes:

   `$('#treeview-checkbox').treeview({
           debug: true,
           //use this for pre-selecting items:
           data: ['DSS-WIN-OS'] //have the DSS > Windows checkbox checked on page load`
2. There may be some configuration in the treeview for this, or you could add a callback handler...
3. Update the [*type*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) attribute on the reset button to have value *reset*

   `<button id="clearselection" name="clearselection" class="btn btn-inverse" type="reset">Reset Selection</button>`

You can see this working in [this example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hWYEUKRrKdeH6O1hLpwF?p=preview). Note that I changed the form method to GET because I can't have a page with server-side code (e.g. PHP) in that sandbox environment but the handling of the form fields should be similar with a POST technique - e.g. in PHP you should be able to access `$_POST['platforms']` as an array (presuming values were submitted).

Comment: Perfect Integration, now i'm trying to make Parent Node automatically select all chiled nodes, and also trying to create something that allow me to disable some checkbooks based on the radio button selections

Thanks alot